# launchd run command every minute of a specific hour

Tags: launchd, plist

On `man launchd.plist` it says (emphasis mine)

> StartCalendarInterval  This optional key causes the job to be started every
>   calendar interval as specified. **Missing arguments are considered
>   to be wildcard**. The semantics are similar to crontab(5) in how
>   firing dates are specified. Multiple dictionaries may be specified
>   in an array to schedule multiple calendar intervals.

My plist file is `/Users/enricozb/test.plist` and contains

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>Label</key>
    <string>com.enricozb.test</string>
    <key>ProgramArguments</key>
    <array>
        <string>date</string>
    </array>
    <key>StandardOutPath</key>
    <string>/Users/enricozb/test.txt</string>
    <key>StartCalendarInterval</key>
    <dict>
        <key>Hour</key>
        <integer>21</integer>
    </dict>
</dict>
</plist>
```

Notice that `Hour` is set to `21`, aka, 9PM. Also, notice that the command is just basically `date > /Users/enricozb/test.txt`. I ran

```
launchctl load /Users/enricozb/test.plist
launchctl start com.enricozb.test
```

This fires **once** right after the `launchctl start` command, and never again.

I was assuming that since the documentation says that missing arguments are wildcard, that the `Minute` field would be wildcard too. Why is this not running every minute?

Answer (score 4):

***Edit start***

You got it all correct except for enclosing your `<dict>` element inside an `<array>` element. Your script will run every minute from 21:00 to 21:59 with the following as your `StartCalendarInterval` key :

```
    <key>StartCalendarInterval</key>
    <array>
        <dict>
            <key>Hour</key>
            <integer>21</integer>
        </dict>
    </array>
```

If you wanted your script to run every minute, every hour, every day, every year, the following would be the correct (but certainly not obvious)  syntax for that:

```
    <key>StartCalendarInterval</key>
    <array>
        <dict/>
    </array>
```

My original answer (below) would also work, but it's clearly much more tedious! OTOH, if one needed every *other* minute, or certain minutes, it might be useful.

***Edit end***

---

```
<key>StartCalendarInterval</key>
    <array>
        <dict>
            <key>Minute</key>
            <integer>0</integer>
        </dict>
        <dict>
            <key>Minute</key>
            <integer>1</integer>
        </dict>
        <dict>
            <key>Minute</key>
            <integer>2</integer>
        </dict>
        <dict>
            <key>Minute</key>
            <integer>3</integer>
        </dict>
        <dict>
            <key>Minute</key>
            <integer>4</integer>
        </dict>

       ... ad nauseum ...

        <dict>
            <key>Minute</key>
            <integer>59</integer>
        </dict>

    </array>
```

To answer your question, *"Why is this not running every minute?"*, it's only because you failed to enclose `<dict>` inside `<array>`.  FWIW, it seems very odd to me also, and ***WHY*** it's designed this way is an answer I'd like to hear myself. But then I guess Apple could use the defense that "just because the *semantics* are similar does not mean the syntax is."

Comment: This is the syntax that I used, and I still cannot get it to work. I’ve added the full plist to my comment. What version of macOS are you using? I’m on Mojave.

Comment: macOS Catalina 10.15.6: `<array> <dict/> </array>` fires every minute, but `<array><dict><key>Hour</key><integer>21</integer></dict></array>` does not (with the right time). Specifing `Minute` does work again. A bunch of entries *including minute keys* work as well.

Answer (score 2):

I think this is a bug in `launchd`.

If I take out the *hour* designation, it fires every minute.

But if I restrict the plist to only 9pm, then it only fires once.

## Update

This is what I tried (with the hour changed to ’12’ because that’s the current hour when I tried to test it).

The ’test.txt’ file never gets created.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>Label</key>
    <string>com.tjluoma.everyminute</string>
    <key>Program</key>
    <string>/bin/date</string>
    <key>StandardOutPath</key>
    <string>/Users/tjluoma/Desktop/test.txt</string>
    <key>StartCalendarInterval</key>
    <array>
        <dict>
            <key>Hour</key>
            <integer>12</integer>
        </dict>
    </array>
</dict>
</plist>
```

This *does* create/update the file *every minute*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>Label</key>
    <string>com.tjluoma.everyminute</string>
    <key>Program</key>
    <string>/bin/date</string>
    <key>StandardOutPath</key>
    <string>/Users/tjluoma/Desktop/test.txt</string>
    <key>StartCalendarInterval</key>
    <array>
        <dict/>
    </array>
</dict>
</plist>
```

Comment: Not a bug... please see my (heavily) edited [answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/376324/149366).

Comment: Within `<array> ... </array>` you `<dict/>` and I've not seen that before, only `<dict>` and `</dict>`. What's the significance of having the `/` where it is in `<dict/>`?

Comment: `<dict/>` is shorthand for `<dict></dict>` in XML.

Comment: I should add that all of my examples from <https://www.soma-zone.com/LaunchControl/>. I don’t write any of these plists myself. Life is too short and LaunchControl is too good.